# Javascript show hide based on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I've got some rough-and-ready code that allows me to filter some results based on two radio buttons. I'm struggling to add a third variant that will serve as a 'show all', ie to display all four divs at once. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<p class="text1">Variants
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-2" id="type_0" checked="checked" />
   Variant 1</label>
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-1" id="type_1" />
   Variant 2</label>
</p>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name$='type']").click(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value=='variant-2') {
    $(".variant-1").show();
     $(".variant-2").hide();
}
else if(value=='variant-1') {
 $(".variant-2").show();
  $(".variant-1").hide();
 }
});
 $(".variant-1").show();
 $(".variant-2").hide();
});

</script>


<div class="variant-1">Variant 1</div>

<div class="variant-2">Variant 2</div>

<div class="variant-1">Variant 1.1</div>

<div class="variant-2">Variant 2.1</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/WyxmF/1

```
<p class="text1">Variants
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-2" id="type_0" checked="checked" />
   Variant 1</label>
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-1" id="type_1" />
   Variant 2</label>
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-all" id="type_all" />
   All</label>
</p>

<div class="variant variant-1">Variant 1</div>

<div class="variant variant-2">Variant 2</div>

<div class="variant variant-1">Variant 1.1</div>

<div class="variant variant-2">Variant 2.1</div>
​


$("input[name$='type']").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'variant-2') {
        $(".variant-1").show();
        $(".variant-2").hide();
    }
    else if (value == 'variant-1') {
        $(".variant-2").show();
        $(".variant-1").hide();
    }
    else if (value == 'variant-all') {
        $(".variant").show();
    }
});
$(".variant-1").show();
$(".variant-2").hide();​
```

Comment: However, a better way, would be to use two classes, `variant` and `variant-1` (or 2) so you know what a `variant` is, and can then differentiate the type, something more like http://jsfiddle.net/WyxmF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution based on attribute 'class' ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abaksheyev/KTKjm/)***

***HTML***

```
   <p class="text1">Variants
 <label>
   <input class="gr" type="radio" name="type" value="one" id="type_0" checked="checked" />
   Variant 1</label>
 <label>
   <input class="gr" type="radio" name="type" value="two" id="type_1" />   Variant 2</label>
<label>
   <input class="gr" type="radio" name="type" value="all" id="type_all" />  All</label>

</p>

</br>
</br>
</br>


<div class="variant-1 one all">Variant 1</div>

<div class="variant-2 two all">Variant 2</div>

<div class="variant-1 one all">Variant 1.1</div>

<div class="variant-2 two all">Variant 2.1</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gr").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.all').hide();        
        $('.'+value ).show();
    })
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/h6Q38/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='type']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'variant-2') {
            $(".variant-1").show();
            $(".variant-2").hide();
        }
        else if (value == 'variant-1') {
            $(".variant-2").show();
            $(".variant-1").hide();
        }
        else{
            $(".variant-2").show();
            $(".variant-1").show();
        }
    });
    $(".variant-1").show();
    $(".variant-2").hide();
});​

<p class="text1">Variants
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-2" id="type_0" checked="checked" />
   Variant 1</label>
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-1" id="type_1" />
   Variant 2</label>
    <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-3" id="type_2" />
   Show All</label>
</p>

<div class="variant-1">Variant 1</div>

<div class="variant-2">Variant 2</div>

<div class="variant-1">Variant 1.1</div>

<div class="variant-2">Variant 2.1</div>​
```

**UPDATED CODE**

Better way to reduce repition

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='type']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == 'variant-3'){
            $('[class*=variant]').show();
        }
        else{
             $('[class*=variant]').hide();
             $('.'+ value ).show();
        }
    }).click();
});​
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/h6Q38/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it simplifies your if else

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='type']").click(function() {        
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'showall') {
            $('div[class^=variant]').show();
        } else {
            var $thisClass = $('div.' + value);
            $thisClass.show();
            $('div[class^=variant]').not($thisClass).hide();
        }
    });
    $("input[value=variant-1]").click();
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C4qJr/2/)

Comment: Thankyou for your advice and helping to simplify my code - always learning!